# We should put these tags under [lock] and [keys]

Tags: discussion, tags

(The only reason these are the same question is for the pun.  If they should be split, I can split them.)

Neither of these have tag wiki entries.  As of now, [lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lock) has 182 questions, [keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keys) has 82.

[lock](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/lock) has questions about a variety of topics, including screen locks, folders having a lock icon, APT being locked, etc.  [keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/keys) has questions about SSH key pairs, gnome keyring, media buttons on laptops, as well as general keyboard topics.

IMO, both of these should be removed.  We have much better tags that can be used.

Answer (score 8, accepted):

Agreed. These tags are overly broad and should be removed, since we already have specific tags such as [ssh-keys](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/ssh-keys) and [gnome-keyring](https://askubuntu.com/questions/tagged/gnome-keyring).